# How to use a newer version of an assembly that Orchard uses

Tags: c#, .net, orchardcms

I want to implement a custom module in Orchard CMS. the problem is that I want to reference libraries used by various Orchard CMS modules, which are referencing older versions of these libraries

I want my plugin/module to be self sustaining - I don't want to require modifications be made to orchard.web's web.config file. i want users who are running orchard without a source enlistment to be able to utilize my modules.

How can I achieve this? [This page](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/6406#issuecomment-216208329) describes my own module's `web.config` as more or less meaningless in terms of binding redirects... I tried just putting these references (the libraries in question are `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` and `Newtonsoft.Json`) in the bin directory of my module and reference from there, but when I attempt to install the module I get an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

I have read a little bit about Orchard's `App_Data/dependencies` folder and the `orchard.web/bin` folder but I am having trouble understanding how it all comes together. How can I allow my module to use a new version of a library while still allowing orchard modules to utilize an old (incompatible) version of that library?

Comment: I've bumped into this before in the past but always got by simply using Orchard's version. Presumably that's not an option for you but do you really need the newer versions of the libraries?

Comment: Thanks for the question. In some cases, it's not an option to use an older version of a library. For example, certain libraries have a dependency on a newer version of the library than Orchard uses - for example new methods that didn't exist or changed method signatures.

Comment: Binding redirects should do the trick.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy sorry for the late reply.. you're saying all I should have to do is throw the updated dll in my module's bin folder, and modify my own module's web.config?

Comment: Not the modules web config, that's inactive. The app's.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy So in instances where I don't have access to the app's web.confg (ie my module is being installed standalone on another Orchard site), it's impossible to do? I guess it's not entirely unreasonable to suggest that they modify their web.config to use it?

Comment: To confirm.. I have a newer version of newtonsoft.dll in my module's bin directory, and the a dependent assembly node the following bindredirect: <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />. However, unfortunately, I still get the error: "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Comment: That's right: assembly binding is pretty much a global thing.

Comment: Next step would be to attach a debugger and look at the modules window to see what is being loaded and from where. I'm suspecting something pushes the old one to the bin, so you might also want to check what version actually ends up there.

Comment: Note that the modules bins are never where assemblies are loaded from. First they are copied to the app's bin and then they are loaded from there.

Comment: I wrote a complete answer, see below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Orchard does a good job of giving the illusion of a composed application with very few global, application-level entities that can't be overridden at the module level. Assembly loading is one of those places where it breaks down however. When the application is compiled and loaded, including when dynamic compilation enters the mix, the assemblies generated and depended upon by all the modules are gathered and copied into the global application's bin folder. Module's bin folders are actually just places assemblies are copied from, but the actual loading happens from the app's bin. So in the end, if you want to know what exactly is loaded into the app, you need to look in the top-level bin folder. If you find the wrong version in here, it's time to dig further and look at what versions modules have, and in what order they are contributing. If I'm not mistaken, that would depend on their dependencies on one another, the outermost dependencies getting their assemblies copied last, and thus winning. That means that you may have some power to tweak what makes it by tweaking module dependency order in their manifest.

The second thing that is global, because that's just the way ASP.NET is, is assembly binding configuration. There are ASP.NET settings that can be set at the directory level, but assembly binding needs to happen at the top, because the app is just one app domain in the end, and only one copy of each assembly will be loaded. Of course, that's a problem in any modular application, because modules had different expectations of versions of their dependencies at the times they were written. .NET deals with this with binding redirects, which basically are a way of instructing the runtime to just assume that everything will be fine if it loads that specific version. It will also tell assemblies that depend on those redirected dependencies a lie, in that it pretends that the version they expected was present, but will actually use the version specified in the redirect. It often works, but not always (breaking changes happen). And if that specific version that you redirect to isn't actually available, either in the GAC or in the app's bin, it will fail.

So in summary:

- There's nothing modules can do at their level to unify the version of an assembly that the app will use, it needs to be a binding redirect set at the application level.
- The assembly being redirected to must end up in the app's bin.
- A module can affect, to a degree, what assemblies get deployed to the app's bin by changing its dependency order in its manifest (but that requires knowledge of those other modules).

Of course, ideally, all third-party modules, as well as Orchard core modules, would get updated to use the latest, but that's clearly rarely an option.

Comment: Bertrand, I really appreciate the thoroughness of your comments and answer. Manually overwriting the .dll in the top level bin folder, and setting a binding redirect, has resolved the errors I was getting.
I do wish to clarify the difference between the .bin folder and the App_Data\Dependencies folder. From what I understand, the Dependencies folder is the one that is copied to during dynamic compilation processes etc. But when I initially put the new dll in there with a binding redirect, I got no results.

Comment: I'll accept this answer due to the fact that my issues (at least in development site) have been resolved by copying to the root bin folder and using a binding redirect. I would really appreciate if you could answer my above query as the way I understand it, the bin folder is just generated at compilation from source whereas the App_Data\Dependencies contents are generated via dynamic compilation. After your answer I'll assume it's not that black and white.... Until then, I'll get debugging as per your comments above and try to apply a real fix so that others may use my module. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `App_Data/Dependencies` folder is used because a) it is known to be writeable and b) won't get automatically picked up by ASP.NET on every change and trigger the app to restart. But once it's been built with all the pieces from all modules, that all gets copied to `/bin`, the app restarts, and loads the updated assemblies. In other words, nothing ever gets loaded from `Dependencies`, only `bin`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm going to do some digging into the source code based on the information you've given me (I have a bit more of a clue what to look for now) and try to improve my understanding of how Orchard puts the pieces together. I'm (clearly) not an Orchard expert, but if I can improve my confidence in this area I might try to update the appropriate documentation if that is okay -- I have noticed a few to-dos and so on that would be nice to fill in. Look forward to working with Orchard a little more and getting to know how all the pieces fit together. Cheers.